# Preparing data in json on backend and populating data via ajax on frontend, what're the problems?

Tags: javascript, json, architecture

Preparing data in json format on backend and populating data to templates via ajax on frontend, what're the problems with this architect design? Assume all visitors use javascript-capable browsers, and we don't care about the number of HTTP connections that a webpage has to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That architecture is fine, in fact it is the architecture enforced by some frameworks like javascriptmvc.

Just some comments:

- Depending on the complexity of the templates the rendering can be slow in the client side.
- If you have a lot of simultaneous requests from the same client to get data, they will be queued to keep a maximum of two simultaneous requests delaying the page load.